# why does Uri.fromFile(new File(url)) work and Uri.parse(url) not in open pdf by intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

The code below can open pdf file by intent and works well:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(url)), "application/pdf");    
if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but if I change `Uri.fromFile(new File(url))` to `Uri.parse(url)`, just like below, and it will fail to open pdf file. Why?

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
```

I know the class type of instance that the two method return is different, but is this the key that the code above works?
By the way, the url is right and the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Uri is Type used to provide content to the ContentProvider. The uri is the path to a pdf file right? How would Uri.parse know that what you're passing it is a pdf and not just a url? This is why fromFile is needed.